# Karate report configuration issue

Tags: report, karate

In my Karate project, I have the following global config:

```
 karate.configure('report', {showLog:true, showAllSteps:false});
```

Because I want cleaner reports, and don't want to show all steps that starts with *.

So, with above config, * print, Given, When etc steps still get reported as I expect, however, these steps will not be included in report if in a feature that is called.  Is this a bug, or maybe something I am missing?  If expected behavior how can I have *print steps show in reports, even if within a called feature?

I'm using the parallel runner with Junit5 as per example in documentation.

Here's an example:

```
Scenario: test API call

    * call read('classpath:apitest/commonAPIcall.feature')

    * print "contents of this print step will be included in report as expected"
```

And here's the scenario I'm calling:

```
@ignore
Feature: common API call

Scenario:

    # GET details should be included in report but its not
    Given url 'https://www.apiurl.com/someCommonCall/'
    When method get
    Then status 200

    * print "contents of this print step is NOT included in report as I would like"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We had some bugs against 0.9.5, e.g: https://github.com/intuit/karate/issues/1078

So can you please try 0.9.6.RC4 and confirm if all this is fixed ?

Else, please follow this process: https://github.com/intuit/karate/wiki/How-to-Submit-an-Issue

Comment: Thanks, with 0.9.6.RC4, I noticed changes, like the Parallel runner now puts out the surefire html report (it did not with 0.9.5).  However still the same issue where in the cucumber reports, not including steps I would expect with showAllSteps false for called scenarios.  Also the surefire report is including fields Im not expecting.  I will report, thanks for feedback.

Comment: @Renaud fine. also see if you can contribute code :) also please see this new annotation: https://github.com/intuit/karate/tree/develop#reportfalse - this has been very troublesome to implement, so it may require community contribution